# React base64 maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: reactjs, svg, base64

I am trying to build a home page that contains a svg as background image. This svg has three  tags entangled which consist of a base64 encoded string( Illustrator puts the svg out like this). All together the svg is cointains 12 million characters which is quite long but should be possible right? The svg files load in my browser. But when I am trying to build in prod I get an error:

`./src/components/home/HomeSvgBg.js
Module build failed: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at String.match (<anonymous>)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)`

When I cut the string in half it builds but shows obviously only half the svg. Could this be a configuration in Webpack or has it anything to do with the maximum build memory? Or is the svg just to large to render?

Here is my webpack.config

```
'use strict';

const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
const SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin = require('sw-precache-webpack-plugin');
const eslintFormatter = require('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter');
const ModuleScopePlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin');
const paths = require('./paths');
const getClientEnvironment = require('./env');
const publicPath = paths.servedPath;
const shouldUseRelativeAssetPaths = publicPath === './';
const publicUrl = publicPath.slice(0, -1);
// Get environment variables to inject into our app.
const env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);

if (env.stringified['process.env'].NODE_ENV !== '"production"') {
    throw new Error('Production builds must have NODE_ENV=production.');
}

const cssFilename = 'static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css';

const extractTextPluginOptions = shouldUseRelativeAssetPaths
    // Making sure that the publicPath goes back to to build folder.
    ? { publicPath: Array(cssFilename.split('/').length).join('../') }
    : {};
module.exports = {
    // Don't attempt to continue if there are any errors.
    bail: true,
    devtool: 'source-map',
    // In production, we only want to load the polyfills and the app code.
    entry: [require.resolve('./polyfills'), paths.appIndexJs],
    output: {
        // The build folder.
        path: paths.appBuild,
        filename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].js',
        chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].chunk.js',
        // We inferred the "public path" (such as / or /my-project) from homepage.
        publicPath: publicPath,
        // Point sourcemap entries to original disk location
        devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
            path.relative(paths.appSrc, info.absoluteResourcePath),
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: ['node_modules', paths.appNodeModules].concat(
            // It is guaranteed to exist because we tweak it in `env.js`
            process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean),
        ),
        extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.jsx'],
        alias: {
            'react-native': 'react-native-web',
        },
        plugins: [
            new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc),
        ],
    },
    module: {
        strictExportPresence: true,
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                enforce: 'pre',
                use: [
                    {
                        options: {
                            formatter: eslintFormatter,

                        },
                        loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
                    },
                ],
                include: paths.appSrc,
            },
            {
                exclude: [
                    /\.html$/,
                    /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    /\.css$/,
                    /\.json$/,
                    /\.bmp$/,
                    /\.gif$/,
                    /\.jpe?g$/,
                    /\.png$/,
                ],
                loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
                options: {
                    name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
                },
            },
            // "url" loader works just like "file" loader but it also embeds
            // assets smaller than specified size as data URLs to avoid requests.
            {
                test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
                loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
                options: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
                },
            },
            // Process JS with Babel.
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                include: paths.appSrc,
                loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),

            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
                    Object.assign(
                        {
                            fallback: require.resolve('style-loader'),
                            use: [
                                {
                                    loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                                    options: {
                                        importLoaders: 1,
                                        minimize: true,
                                        sourceMap: true,
                                    },
                                },
                                {
                                    loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                                    options: {
                                        ident: 'postcss', // https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#complex-options
                                        plugins: () => [
                                            require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                                            autoprefixer({
                                                browsers: [
                                                    '>1%',
                                                    'last 4 versions',
                                                    'Firefox ESR',
                                                    'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                                                ],
                                                flexbox: 'no-2009',
                                            }),
                                        ],
                                    },
                                },
                            ],
                        },
                        extractTextPluginOptions,
                    ),
                ),
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(env.raw),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: true,
            template: paths.appHtml,
            minify: {
                removeComments: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                useShortDoctype: true,
                removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                keepClosingSlash: true,
                minifyJS: true,
                minifyCSS: true,
                minifyURLs: true,
            },
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false,
                comparisons: false,
            },
            output: {
                comments: false,
            },
            sourceMap: true,
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: cssFilename,
        }),
        new ManifestPlugin({
            fileName: 'asset-manifest.json',
        }),
        new SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin({
            dontCacheBustUrlsMatching: /\.\w{8}\./,
            filename: 'service-worker.js',
            logger (message) {
                if (message.indexOf('Total precache size is') === 0) {
                    return;
                }
                console.log(message);
            },
            minify: true,
            navigateFallback: publicUrl + '/index.html',
            navigateFallbackWhitelist: [/^(?!\/__).*/],
            staticFileGlobsIgnorePatterns: [/\.map$/, /asset-manifest\.json$/],
            stripPrefix: paths.appBuild.replace(/\\/g, '/') + '/',
        }),
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
    ],
    node: {
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty',
    },
};
```

Comment: Perhaps issue is with webpack configuration

Comment: Which part of the webpack configuration would restrict this stack size?

Comment: Not sure. Need to look at your webpack config to figure out

Comment: I added the webpack config to the issue.
Thank you!